# Invalid JSON String - UnsupportedMediaType - RestSharp POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, restsharp

So I was making a POST request using [RestSharp](http://www.restsharp.org) to an endpoint that needs `application\json.` I initialized the RestClient and request and used 
`request.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/json")`
and made subsequent calls to `request.AddParameter()` but the error I get is `Invalid JSON String` with a status code of `UnsupportedMediaType` and also mentions `Expected application/json or text/json body.` Any idea of what's going on? How do I fix this?

I tried using a custom serializer as well, but to no avail. The request works successfully on Chrome's Advanced Rest Client.

Comment: Add code to understand where you are going wrong

Comment: Download postman, add your call, hit copy code button its in restSharp

Comment: @Caz1224 the code is incorrect, it does the same thing I've been doing all this while :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the standard code for executing the call via Rest Sharp, passing data as Http Body

```
var client = new RestClient("<Http Url>");

var request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", "<Valid Json>", ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Check out the following [link](http://itanex.blogspot.in/2012/02/restsharp-and-advanced-post-requests.html) too

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any neat way to generate the "<valid json>" string?

Comment: yes, json is just a text format, either check it in http://jsonlint.com/ or better take a C# object and do JsonConvert.Serialize using Newtonsoft Json binary, it will always produce valid json